# FSRM unable to create new reports after removing old LUN

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, storage, cluster, reporting

We are running a 3 node failover cluster file service based on server 2008 R2 and iSCSI Storage Arrays.  We have recently migrated all storage from one cluster file service on one LUN to a new file service on a new LUN.  The old file service had a few storage reports assigned to send large file reports etc...

Since removing the old LUN completely from the system, the file server resource manager will not let us create any more storage reports on any drives.  We had not removed the old reports before discconecting the old LUN but have since removed them.

We select new storage report, add a drive or folder, setup the report data section.  The Delivery and Schedule tabs are both inaccessable giving the error "The file Server Resource Manager service encountered an unexpected error."

The event log lists an Event ID of 8197 with this error:

"File Server Resource Manager Service error: Unexpected error.

Error-specific details:
   Error: ISClusResource::get_Disk(...), 0x80070490, Element not found."

1. We have tried moving the file service to each of the cluster nodes
   and they all give the same error.
2. Tried removing the FSRM role from all servers and re-adding.
3. Have inspected the FSRM system volume information folder on the server drives for any reference
   to the old LUN.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this further?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution:  After reading http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/612946/sql-2008-sp2-fails-install-on-a-cluster-with-windows-2008-64-bit-and-veritas-storage-foundation

It turns out although we had removed the file storage LUN from the cluster we had also removed an old CSV.  Instead of deleting the CSV we had put the resource in offline mode in case we needed to restore it in the future (failure of new CSV etc...)  After deleting the offline resource we were able to create reports again.

Bottom Line: Don't have any offline storage resources in your cluster if you need to create/edit storage reports.